# CSRF Token in every response

Tags: security, spring-security, csrf

I'm working on the security of a spring-based project and I've found this filter: [spring-security-csrf-filter](https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-filter)

It promises to add the csrf token in every response, and I ask you, is it safe?

I couldn't find any best practice about when to return the token.

I made some tests with this filter and the result is that spring returns the token even if I request a non-existing endpoint.

Comment: Yes, CSRF tokens should be refreshed on every response.

Comment: So, on the client side, I should have something that extracts the token from every response and not just the first time, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @1615903 that is incorrect. Session-based CSRF is fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Why use some random filter when Spring has one built-in?
2. Safe from what? What is your threat model?

It's fine to return the CSRF token in every response, even if you don't use it. The same-origin policy prevents other sites from reading the response.

Comment: The difference between the filter and the built-in version is written in the github page that I linked in the question. I'm very new in security methods so I did not completely understand how does the same-origin policy prevents other sites from reading the response, and so, the token